React native bare Expo integration not loading local PNG & GIF images
I am working on integration of EXPO for eas updates in my react native cli app (Bare app integration), I am able to generate eas build & the build also works fine, but the issue is - I have PNG images in my app which are not getting loaded, though the SVG's are working fine, I have tried changing metro.config.js by exclusively adding PNG & GIF in the filter but it doesn't work.
I have tried using expo-image also but that too doesn't work.
My current metro.config.js looks like this
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');
const { mergeConfig } = require("@react-native/metro-config");

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
const { assetExts, sourceExts } = defaultConfig.resolver;

const config = {
    transformer: {
        babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer")
    },
    resolver: {
        assetExts: assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== "svg"),
        sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg"]
    }
};

module.exports = mergeConfig(defaultConfig, config);


Please help.

Tried changing metro.config.js
Tried seeking help from EXPO discord channel
Tried logging the images, and that is getting logged fine.

